# Ionic nav back button is not displaying

Tags: ionic-framework, navbar

I have tried several code samples to get a back button in my home page. I couldnt see the nav back button. Where i am wrong?

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
    <i class="button button-icon my-back-button"></i>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-side-menu-content>                
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-header-bar class="dark-bg expanded">            
             <a href="#" class="logo"><span>R</span></a>
             <p align="center"> My App</p>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="stable-bg has-expanded-header">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="app.settings">
                    Settings
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="app.profile">
                    Profile
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="app.logout">
                    Log out
                </ion-item>            
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

### Home page code

```
<ion-view title="Home">
<ion-content>
  <div class="list card">
   <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" ui-sref="makerequest">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-list-outline"></i>
    Make New Request
  </a>
  <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" ui-sref="viewrequest">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-copy"></i>
    View Request
  </a>
  </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[image: screenshot]

Added my home page code above.

Regards,
Sabarisri

Comment: Can you show your login page code?

Comment: @mrust the page i mentioned is home page. I have added the code above